# How to refresh the contents of the MVC 3 partial View placed in JQuery Dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, partial-page-refresh, asp.net-mvc-partialview

My situation is very common.
I have a master detail environment on my web administration.
I need to be able to select one record among around 3500 from a dialog.

This is the reason why I need pagination.
My implementation is using JQuery Dialog and MVC 3 partial View in it.
I need the possibility to refresh the contents of the already opened JQuery dialog without refreshing the underline page.

After any page click on the partial View in the JQuery dialog

```
 <dt>
    <a href="/News/SelectArtist?PageId=2">B</a>
 </dt>
 <dt>
    <a href="/News/SelectArtist?PageId=3">C</a>
 </dt>
```

My page has been refreshed and the the JQuery dialog disapeared.

Is there some kind of solution for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear if the News/SelectArtist is the controller action that should return your partial view, but here how I would do this.

You can call this action via ajax and refresh the content of your jQuery dialog.

Suppose your jQuery dialog has a div wrapping the entire content (from your partial view):

```
<div id="dialog-content">
...
<!-- this is the content of your partial view -->
</div>
```

Add a css class to each of your page links and a data-pageid to call your SelectArtist action like this:

```
<dt>
<a class="page-trigger" href="#" data-pageid="2">B</a>
</dt>
```

From a script block:

```
$(function() {
  $('.page-trigger').click(function() {
    var pageId = $(this).data('pageid');
    $.ajax('/News/SelectArtist?PageId=' + pageId, { }, function(data) {
      $('#dialog-content').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Make sure your SelectArtist action have the `[HttpPost]` attribute. Your dialog content would update without a page request.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectArtist()
{
  int pageId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["pageId']);
  ...
  return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: The SelectArtist is the controller action that returns my partial View. I have all parts you described. The entire form is wrapped by the Ajax.BeginForm("SelectArtist", "News", FormMethod.Post, null).

Comment: Maybe this is the problem. Maybe I need to remove the BeginForm part. Anyway I do not understand what needs to be the format of the data (html?) beacuse I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and I am forwarding the @model that is a list of items.

Comment: With the solution I suggested you don't need the Ajax.BeginForm, the click on a link is handled by jQuery and the post is made to the controller's action which return your partial view. You might need to post more code so it's easier to understand the situation.